# Seach by DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

*Hello.How can i implement search by Datetime. When i try this code i get no results.*
*I tried with Contains and Equal but it doesn't work*
*Please help, I will, very grateful.*
**Attaching photos**:

*................................................*

[My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sUVR.png),,,
[EmptyView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtYn7.png)

```
public class People: BaseDeletableModel<int>
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string FilePdfUrl { get; set; }
}


 public class PeopleViewModel : IMapFrom<People>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MinLength(2)]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birthday")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Upload your Presentation in pdf format")]
    [Required]
    public IFormFile FilePdf { get; set; }

    public string FilePdfUrl { get; set; }

 }



   public class PeopleService : IPeopleService
 {
   public IEnumerable<T> GetByDate<T>(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var peoples= this.peopleRepository.All().Where(x => x.DateOfBirth == 
        dateTime);

        return peoples.To<T>().ToList();
    }
 }

   


    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var viewModel = new ListViewModel();
        var peoples= this.peopleService.GetByDate<PeopleViewModel>(date);

        viewModel.Peoples= peoples;

        return this.View("Listing", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Would you please show us your `search query`?

Comment: You need to provide more information for someone to be able to help you. Please share some more code to show the part where you query and have you tried debugging to see what the dates look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `date format` you're matching with the record. You must change the search textbox to type `date`

Then in your `controller` convert `date` to `string` and then apply `where` clause

```
public ActionResult Search(DateTime date)
{
    var list = db.table.ToList();
    var result = list.Where(x => x.DateOfBirth.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == date.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```